# Эмулятор gprs-модема

Tags: эмулятор, модемы, gprs

Доброго времени суток, друзья! Есть вопрос, существует ли полноценный эмулятор GPRS-модема? Программа, которая позволит обмануть программно, создать виртуальный порт и модем для работы с ним на программном уровне?

Answer (score 1):

Почему не попробовать TClientSocket и TServer Socket (Delphi)?

Comment: но это же на локальном компьютере будет передача данных. А мне хотелось бы чтобы передавать данные на виртуальный модем, а принимать данные с другого виртуального модема.